# How do I see the expanded macro code that's causing my compile error?

Tags: debugging, rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros, rust-decl-macros

I have a compile error involving a macro:

```
<mdo macros>:6:19: 6:50 error: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
<mdo macros>:6 bind ( $ e , move | $ p | mdo ! { $ ( $ t ) * } ) ) ; (
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<mdo macros>:1:1: 14:36 note: in expansion of mdo!
<mdo macros>:6:27: 6:50 note: expansion site
<mdo macros>:1:1: 14:36 note: in expansion of mdo!
<mdo macros>:6:27: 6:50 note: expansion site
<mdo macros>:1:1: 14:36 note: in expansion of mdo!
src/parser.rs:30:42: 37:11 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Unfortunately, the macro is recursive so it's hard to figure out what the compiler is complaining about, plus it seems like the line numbers are for the expanded macro rather than my code.

How can I see the expanded macro? Is there a flag I can pass to rustc (or even better, cargo) to dump this out?

(This macro is from [rust-mdo](https://github.com/TeXitoi/rust-mdo), though I don't think it matters.)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`cargo rustc --profile=check -- -Zunpretty=expanded`, but a more concise alternative is the [cargo-expand](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) crate. It provides a Cargo subcommand `cargo expand` which prints the result of macro expansion. It also passes the expanded code through [`prettyplease`](https://github.com/dtolnay/prettyplease) which generally results in much more readable code than the default output from rustc.

Install by running `cargo install cargo-expand`.

Comment: cargo install cargo-expand —features=prettyprint/regex-fancy will be slightly slower but avoids a c++ dependency so is more likely to build cleanly.

Comment: cargo-expand does not depend on prettyprint or any C++ dependencies.

Comment: You should mention you are the author of the crate

Comment: It's 2021 and things have changed a bit. You can now use: `rustc -Zunpretty=expanded some.rs`. See Enselic's answer for more details.

Comment: Nice `cargo expand` but not so nice not adding the typical "I wrote this" disclaimer ;-p

Answer (score 54):

If you want to see the expanded code even before compiling, you can use `Expand Macro Recursively` feature of [`rust-analyzer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer) (a vscode extension for Rust language).

[image]

Answer (score 51):

Yes, you can pass a special flag to `rustc`, called `--pretty=expanded`:

```
% cat test.rs
fn main() {
    println!("Hello world");
}
% rustc -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded test.rs
#![feature(no_std)]
#![no_std]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::v1::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate "std" as std;
fn main() {
    ::std::old_io::stdio::println_args(::std::fmt::Arguments::new_v1({
                                                                         static __STATIC_FMTSTR:
                                                                                &'static [&'static str]
                                                                                =
                                                                             &["Hello world"];
                                                                         __STATIC_FMTSTR
                                                                     },
                                                                     &match ()
                                                                          {
                                                                          ()
                                                                          =>
                                                                          [],
                                                                      }));
}
```

You need to allow it first, however, by passing `-Z unstable-options`.

Since Rust 1.1 you can pass these arguments to Cargo, like this:

```
cargo rustc -- -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded
```

Comment: As of 1.19 this command `cargo rustc -- -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded` is now only available on nightly.

Comment: Why it's only in nightly?(

Comment: @BogdanMart Because it uses an unstable option, but fear not, you can easily use it. Run `rustup install nightly`, then `rustup run nightly cargo rustc -- -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded`.

Comment: So, for three (and counting) years, this capability has never been "stabilized"?

Comment: Likely less about stabilization and more that they don't want to commit to supporting it.

Comment: @jhfrontz A lot of functionality isn't stabilized, because it means it's always available even if they deprecate it, and isn't meant to be used except as a debugging or internal feature. `-Z timings`, `-Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded`, most `rustfmt` lints are all nightly only.

Answer (score 17):

Starting with `nightly-2021-07-28`, one must pass `-Zunpretty=expanded` instead of `-Zunstable-options --pretty=expanded`, like this:

```
% rustc -Zunpretty=expanded test.rs
```

or:

```
% cargo rustc -- -Zunpretty=expanded
```

#### Relevant rustc commits

The `--pretty` argument was removed from `nightly-2021-07-28` via [this commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/23bbd65d968ef385fa7a7cd90ea8252bd78081b1).
Support for `-Zunpretty=expanded` was added to `nightly-2018-01-24` via [this commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/ebfa6c709aecb12a164695912785643d916e75fb).