# Is it possible to get the expansion of a single macro instead of the whole file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-macros

I just found [How do I see the expanded macro code that's causing my compile error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580386/how-do-i-see-the-expanded-macro-code-thats-causing-my-compile-error/28580527). Is it possible to get the expansion of a single macro instead of the whole file?

Comment: Wow from +6 to -3. @Shepmaster I think people weren't happy with your editing. Just joking ;)

Comment: Your question was brought up on Meta, and they did not feel that the question's rating was on par with its quality. Next time, please show additional effort in your questions.

Comment: @E_net4 do you have a link to the meta thread?

Comment: @TimDiekmann https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373705/1233251

Answer (score 20):

The [`cargo-expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) command is really just a thin wrapper around `cargo rustc -- -Zunstable-options --pretty=expanded`, which is itself a blunt instrument. You can't target a specific macro.

However, since [version 0.4](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand/releases/tag/0.4.0), you can reduce some noise by specifying an extra path argument to expand only macros used by that module:

```
$ cargo expand path::to::module
```

Answer (score 7):

"Show expanded macro" and "Show recursively expanded macro" commands were [recently added](https://intellij-rust.github.io/2018/08/06/changelog-80.html) to [IntelliJ Rust](https://intellij-rust.github.io/).

A gif demo from [CLion blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/08/intellij-rust-features-entry-one-macros/):

[image: Demo]

Comment: How can I do this without intellij ?

Comment: It's a part of the plugin's logic, so I guess that you can't use it outside of IntelliJ-Rust.