# Is there a way to view expanded macros on non-nightly Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I realise this has been asked before and the answer was to use the `-Z` option with `rustc`, but that only works with the nightly build of Rust as of Rust 1.31.

Is there an alternative when using the stable build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. This is only available on nightly Rust.

When using rustup, however, there's no reason to **not** have both stable and nightly Rust installed. You can then just do `rustc +nightly -Z ...`, continuing to compile your code with stable.

See also:

- [Is it possible to have multiple coexisting Rust installations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22758779/155423)
- [How do I see the expanded macro code that's causing my compile error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28580386/155423)
- [Is it possible to get the expansion of a single macro instead of the whole file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51917354/155423)

Comment: thanks for this.
What is the reason for not being able to see expanded macros in the stable build?

Comment: @John See [issue #43364](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43364) for a full discussion. One primary reason I know of is that the expanded code might not even compile — it's not guaranteed to have the same semantics as the original code.