# What does `single_use_lifetimes` mean on a struct with derive in a function and how to solve it?

Tags: rust

```
#![warn(single_use_lifetimes)]

fn do_foo() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Foo<'a> {
        bar: &'a u32,
    }
}
```

results in this warning:

```
warning: lifetime parameter `'a` only used once
 --> src/lib.rs:6:16
  |
6 |     struct Foo<'a> {
  |                ^^
  |
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b2c32414ed3d3d043b8487753c63cd94)

What does this warning mean? How can this be solved?

This warning is not shown when omitting either the derive or the function.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward: it's warning you that the lifetime is used only once in the struct.

Comment: Yeah, but how can this be solved? (Without removing the `#![warn(...)]`)

Comment: @trentcl What is the purpose of the warning in this context? The lint is supposed to be for suggesting when unnamed `'_`  lifetimes can be used instead, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: @Peter This looks like a bug given the accepted answer, but at first I thought that maybe it doesn't *have* a purpose in this context, in which case "just turn it off" would be the correct answer. Lots of warnings exist that shouldn't be turned on all the time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose is to prevent code like this, where the lifetime is meaningless to specify explicitly:

```
pub fn example<'a>(_val: SomeType<'a>) {}
```

Instead, it's preferred to use `'_`:

```
pub fn example(_val: SomeType<'_>) {}
```

If you [expand your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28580386/155423) and trim it down, you get this:

```
use std::fmt;

struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a u32,
}

impl<'a> fmt::Debug for Foo<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, _f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result { Ok(()) }
}
```

```
warning: lifetime parameter `'a` only used once
 --> src/lib.rs:9:6
  |
9 | impl<'a> fmt::Debug for Foo<'a> {
  |      ^^
  |
```

That is, the `<'a>` isn't needed, but the derive adds it anyway (because automatically generating code is hard).

I honestly don't know what it would expect the code to change to here, as you can't use `'_` for the struct's generic lifetimes there...

> How can this be solved?

I don't know that it can, without rewriting the `derive` implementation of `Debug`.

See also:

- [println!(), derive(Debug), derive(Clone), and probably many other macros break when using the elided_lifetimes_in_paths lint](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51903)

Comment: Shouldn't `#[automatically_derived]` disallow such warnings?

Comment: Looks like a bug that should be reported.

Comment: @TimDiekmann I *think* that's what I just added a link to, but perhaps the lint name has changed over time?