# Writing a pyo3 function equivalent to a Python function that returns its input object

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I am looking to write a Rust backend for my library, and I need to implement the equivalent of the following function in `pyo3`:

```py
def f(x):
    return x
```

This should return the *same object* as the input, and the function getting the return value should hold a new reference to the input. If I were writing this in the C API I would write it as:

```c
PyObject * f(PyObject * x) {
    Py_XINCREF(x);
    return x;
}
```

In [PyO3](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3), I find it quite confusing to navigate the differences between `PyObject`, `PyObjectRef`, `&PyObject`, `Py<PyObject>`, `Py<&PyObject>`.

The most naive version of this function is:

```rust
extern crate pyo3;

use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyfunction]
pub fn f(_py: Python, x: &PyObject) -> PyResult<&PyObject> {
    Ok(x)
}
```

Among other things, the lifetimes of `x` and the return value are not the same, plus I see no opportunity for `pyo3` to increase the reference count for `x`, and in fact the compiler seems to agree with me:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/lib.rs:4:49
  |
4 | pub fn f(_py: Python, x: &PyObject) -> PyResult<&PyObject> {
  |                                                 ^ expected lifetime parameter
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from `_py` or `x`
```

There may be a way for me to *manually* increase the reference count using the `_py` parameter and use lifetime annotations to make the compiler happy, but my impression is that `pyo3` intends to manage reference counts *itself* using object lifetimes.

What is the proper way to write this function? Should I be attempting to wrap it in a `Py` container?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think your edit makes the title less accurate. The fact that the reference count is increased is *not* something I want to manage or think about in the Rust version. If pyo3 does something else that is equivalent to increasing the reference count that's fine.

Comment: @Shepmaster It's not really a hard requirement. If `pyo3` keeps a single reference to any Python object created and then manages whether or not to release that reference using Rust object lifetimes or something, that would be fine. I don't really know or care, so long as I'm using the correct lifetime management from a pyo3 perspective.

Comment: *the lifetimes of `x` and the return value are not the same* — why do you say this? [Lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision) makes them the same. You could explicitly annotate them to "prove" it: `fn f<'a>(_py: Python, x: &'a PyObject) -> PyResult<&'a PyObject>`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Doing that seems to result in compiler errors anyway, because `pyfunc` is not retaining lifetime parameters.

Comment: *no opportunity for `pyo3` to increase the reference count for `x`* — what prevents it from increasing the reference *before* it hands it to you?

Comment: @Shepmaster I imagine it would have to increase it in the `#[pyfunc]` macro by detecting that the function returns a reference, rather than before it is handed to the function itself, since not all functions increase the reference count of their input parameters.

Comment: As to the lifetime question, that was the gist of the compiler error - this may be the issue @E_net4 was talking about, but I think the point of Python's reference counting is that the lifetime of the input and output should be disconnected (hence the reference counting), so even if the Rust semantics say it has the correct lifetime *as declared*, that's not how the function is intended to be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `PyObject` is [a simple wrapper around a raw pointer](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/ed273982/src/object.rs#L18):

```rust
pub struct PyObject(*mut ffi::PyObject);
```

It has multiple creation functions, each corresponding to different kinds of pointers that we might get from Python. Some of these, such as [`from_borrowed_ptr`](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/ed273982/src/object.rs#L75), call `Py_INCREF` on the passed-in pointer.

Thus, it seems like we can accept a `PyObject`, so long as it was created in the "right" manner.

If we [expand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28580386/155423) this code:

```rust
#[pyfunction]
pub fn example(_py: Python, x: PyObject) -> PyObject {
    x
}
```

We can see this section of code that calls our function:

```rust
let mut _iter = _output.iter();
::pyo3::ObjectProtocol::extract(_iter.next().unwrap().unwrap()).and_then(
    |arg1| {
        ::pyo3::ReturnTypeIntoPyResult::return_type_into_py_result(example(
            _py, arg1,
        ))
    },
)
```

Our argument is created by a call to [`ObjectProtocol::extract`](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/ed273982/src/objectprotocol.rs#L182-L184), which in turn calls `FromPyObject::extract`. This is [implemented for `PyObject`](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/ed273982/src/object.rs#L312-L318) by calling `from_borrowed_ptr`.

Thus, using a bare `PyObject` as the argument type will correctly increment the reference count.

Likewise, when a `PyObject` is dropped in Rust, it will automatically [decrease the reference count](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/ed273982/src/object.rs#L320-L327). When it is returned back to Python, [ownership is transferred](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/ed273982/src/object.rs#L287-L296) and it is up to the Python code to update the reference count appropriately.

---

All investigation done for [commit ed273982](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/tree/ed2739829fdc8d3bb86629c35ae09ebcfe1d116e) from the master branch, corresponding to v0.5.0-alpha.1.

Answer (score 4):

According [to the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52541221/1233251), `pyo3` takes care of building additional boilerplate around our functions in order to keep track of Python reference counting. In particular, the counter is already incremented when passing the object as an argument to the function. Nevertheless, the [`clone_ref`](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/master/src/object.rs#L117) method can be used to explicitly create a new reference to the same object, which will also increment its reference counter.

The output of the function must still be an actual Python object rather than a reference to it (which seems reasonable, as Python does not understand Rust references; `pyo3` seems to ignore lifetime parameters in these functions).

```
#[pyfunction]
fn f(py: Python, x: PyObject) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
    Ok(x.clone_ref(py))
}
```

From playing around with the function in Python land (AKA not a serious testbed), it *at least* seems to work as intended.

```
from dummypy import f

def get_object():
    return f("OK")

a = [1, 2, 3]

if True:
    b = f(a)
    assert b is a
    b[0] = 9001

print(a)

x = get_object()
print(x)
```

Comment: The simplest test would be to call `a = object(); assert f(a) is a`, since the important part is that the input should be the same object as the output.

Comment: @Paul I guess that could be added as well. But I was mostly attempting to check whether the reference count is consistent with the number of variables pointing at the object.