# Why doesn't `use std::{ self, ... };` compile?

Tags: rust

I have no idea why this code can't be compiled with Rust 1.27.0.

This is **test.rs** as it is on my hard drive:

```rust
use std::{
  self,
  io::prelude::*,
  net::{ TcpListener, TcpStream },
};

fn main() {}
```

Output when trying to compile it with `rustc test.rs`:

```
error[E0254]: the name `std` is defined multiple times
 --> test.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     self,
  |     ^^^^ `std` reimported here
  |
  = note: `std` must be defined only once in the type namespace of this module
help: you can use `as` to change the binding name of the import
  |
2 |     self as other_std,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: unused imports: `TcpListener`, `TcpStream`, `io::prelude::*`, `self`
 --> test.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     self,
  |     ^^^^
3 |     io::prelude::*,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
4 |     net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default
```

Comment: Wild guess: std::self references std itself, so you import std twice with a single use statement. Is there a specific reason why you want to import std::self?

Comment: This works fine in a Rust 2018 project, not in a 2015. Please upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This works fine in Rust 2018.** You probably just want to update by adding `edition = "2018"` to your `Cargo.toml` or `--edition=2018` to your `rustc` invocation. Below is the answer for why this doesn't work in Rust 2015.

---

From [the `std::prelude` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/index.html):

> On a technical level, Rust inserts
>
> ```rust
> extern crate std;
> ```
>
> into the crate root of every crate, and
>
> ```rust
> use std::prelude::v1::*;
> ```
>
> into every module.

You can also see that in action when looking at your code [after macro expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580386/how-do-i-see-the-expanded-macro-code-thats-causing-my-compile-error) (e.g. via `cargo-expand`). For your code this results in:

```rust
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#![no_std]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::v1::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
// No external crates imports or anything else.

use std::{
    self,
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
};

fn main() {
    // Empty.
}
```

As you can see, `std` is already in scope due to the `extern crate std;` statement. Thus, importing it another time results in this error.