# How do I solve the error "thread 'main' panicked at 'no current reactor'"?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I am trying to connect to a database:

```
extern crate tokio; // 0.2.6, features = ["full"]
extern crate tokio_postgres; // 0.5.1

use futures::executor;
use tokio_postgres::NoTls;

fn main() {
    let fut = async {
        let (client, connection) = match tokio_postgres::connect("actual stuff", NoTls).await {
            Ok((client, connection)) => (client, connection),
            Err(e) => panic!(e),
        };
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            if let Err(e) = connection.await {
                eprintln!("connection error: {}", e);
            }
        });

        let rows = match client
            .query(
                "SELECT $1 FROM planet_osm_point WHERE $1 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 100",
                &[&"name"],
            )
            .await
        {
            Ok(rows) => rows,
            Err(e) => panic!(e),
        };
        let names: &str = rows[0].get("name");
        println!("{:?}", names);
    };
    executor::block_on(fut);
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

It compiled, but when I ran it, I received the error message

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'no current reactor'
```

Comment: Doesn't it require the "#[tokio::main]" macro above the main function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using many (but not all) Tokio features, you must use the Tokio reactor. In your code, you are trying to use the general executor provided by the futures crate (`executor::block_on`). Using the Tokio executor and reactor is normally done via use of the `#[tokio::main]` macro:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (client, connection) = match tokio_postgres::connect("actual stuff", NoTls).await {
        Ok((client, connection)) => (client, connection),
        Err(e) => panic!(e),
    };
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        if let Err(e) = connection.await {
            eprintln!("connection error: {}", e);
        }
    });

    let rows = match client
        .query(
            "SELECT $1 FROM planet_osm_point WHERE $1 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 100",
            &[&"name"],
        )
        .await
    {
        Ok(rows) => rows,
        Err(e) => panic!(e),
    };
    let names: &str = rows[0].get("name");
    println!("{:?}", names);
}
```

The very first example in [the tokio_postgres docs](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.1/tokio_postgres/) even shows you how to do this:

> ```
> #[tokio::main] // By default, tokio_postgres uses the tokio crate as its runtime.
> async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
> ```

One reason this happens is because you are using [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.6/tokio/fn.spawn.html) which [has this documented](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.6/tokio/fn.spawn.html#panics):

> Panics if called from outside of the Tokio runtime.

See also:

- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)

---

This doesn't print what you want:

```
Err(e) => panic!(e),
```

You want

```
Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
```

Comment: what exactly does the [tokio::main] do exactly I'm confused

Comment: @julia it's a macro. If you expand the macro, you can see exactly what it does: [How do I see the expanded macro code that's causing my compile error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28580386/155423).

Comment: Why do I need to use Tokio reactor if I'm trying to use a feature of `features` and not `tokio`?

Comment: "a feature of `features`"? I don't know what you mean. If you meant **futures**, then [click the link to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423) and use `block_on`. If you need to use `tokio::main`, then you (or a dependency) are using a Tokio feature.