# How do I debug a proc macro?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-proc-macros

So I have a proc macro which is throwing an error.

Specifally `shader!` from [`vulkano_shaders`](https://docs.rs/vulkano-shaders/0.19.0/vulkano_shaders/index.html) is throwing:

```
error: proc macro panicked
  --> src\main.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     vulkano_shaders::shader!{
7  | |         ty: "compute",
8  | |         src: "
9  | |         #version 450
...  |
16 | |         }"
17 | |     }
   | |_____^
   |
   = help: message: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseError(UnknownConstant("Capability", 61))
```

How could I debug this?

#### Minimal reproducible example:

`main.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

mod test_shader {
    vulkano_shaders::shader!{
        ty: "compute",
        src: "
        #version 450

        #extension GL_KHR_shader_subgroup_basic: enable

        void main() {
            uint tester0 = gl_SubgroupSize;
            uint tester1 = gl_SubgroupID;
        }"
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
vulkano = "0.19.0"
vulkano-shaders = "0.19.0"
```

Project zip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fwXNZOTQOlunVAbYWK3rJRmQnDcWvySU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does either `--pretty=expanded` compiler flag or the `cargo-expand` crate help debug the problem?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580386/how-do-i-see-the-expanded-macro-code-thats-causing-my-compile-error

Comment: `--pretty=expanded` gives no different output. `cargo-expand` does give a differnet output, but I'm not sure it's of any use. When commenting out `fn main` for simplicity it gives https://pastebin.com/L8Mtdw1Y, the `test_shader` module specifically is given as `mod test_shader {}`, which I think is fairly useless.
Thank you regardless, anything is something.