# Rust macros query

Tags: rust

Does rust replace all occurrences of macros with some code before compilation or during compilation like how it happens with c/c++ ?

Another aspect of this is how to understand what compiler is doing. Is there any way to dissemble the code and see what’s happening during compilation of rust program.

Comment: Your second question is answered here: [How do I see the expanded macro code that's causing my compile error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580386/how-do-i-see-the-expanded-macro-code-thats-causing-my-compile-error)

Comment: I may be wrong from the link you have given it answers my first question too. I assume that macro gets expanded everywhere it’s used

Comment: Macros are expanded almost everywhere there used- macro invocations are expanded from the outside in, and macros are capable of deleting input, so it is possible that a macro invocation inside another invocation is never expanded.