# How does specifying a function name with no body work while using with Macros in Rust?

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I have a code in which a function name is specified, it is referenced twice later on. This function is placed right below the macros declaration:

```
#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "polkadot_metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot {}
```

This looks to me like a procedural macro, as it takes some code(referenced via word: 'polkadot') and emits the code:

```
let api = ClientBuilder::new()
        .set_client(client)
        .build()
        .await?
        .to_runtime_api::<polkadot::RuntimeApi<polkadot::DefaultConfig>>();
```

I want to understand why the line `pub mod polkadot {}` was placed and how can I explore what API calls are provided in `polkadot`?

Comment: `pub mod polkadot {}` declares and exports a module named `polkadot` without any items, not a function.

Comment: What is the use case to export polkadot? Is that how macros code expands if we want to use a particular module?

Comment: *"How does ... work while using macros"* - this is an attribute macro, and it is given whatever it annotates, in this case a module definition. With that module, the macro can do almost whatever it wants. In this case it appears codegen related based on the file given. I [don't see it documented anywhere](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/tree/master) exactly what this macro is designed to do, but you are able to see what it expands to. See [How do I see the expanded macro code that's causing my compile error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28580386/2189130)

Answer (score 1):

if you `cargo install cargo-expand` that will install a tool that allows you to see the expanded code:

https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand

So if you put in the module name here you can see whatever heavy lifting the macro is doing for you:
`cargo expand path::to::module`